# Installing two Joomla 2.5 and 3.0 on same webserver

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Currently, I have Joomla 2.5 installed and I am trying to install Joomla 3.0 on the same web server.(allowed to run multiple sites)

Under www(root directory), I have installed Joomla 2.5 and working without any problem. 
To install Joomla 3.0, unzipped and uploaded package files to e.g. www/joomla3 folder.
I have set the url e.g. www.joomla3.com to point joomla3 folder.

For joomla 3 configuration, I access url(e.g. www.joomla3.com) but I am getting Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS). If I remove index.php on joomla3 folder than I see web directories. 
Why am I getting this and how can I fix this error. 
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: do you use `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I see htaccess.ini file under www root directory only. Do I have to create(maybe copy existing one) to joomla3 folder?

Comment: .ini? that one doesn't work then, so it doesn't matter

Comment: Did you use something like Virtualhosts?